# Can interface in java access to base class variable?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

When you create interface reference variable to base class type object. Is it possible to access variable in it's base class ?

How can i get "Bmw" which is defined in the car constructor ?

without creating method in interface that must be implemented in base class which will return the variable.

String getName(); and in base class public String getName(){return name;}

```
interface Drive(){

void start();

}

public class Car implements Drive{

String name;

Car(String n){
this.name=n;
}

public void start(){
}
}

public static void main(String [] args){

Drive d = new Car("Bmw");
String nameOfTheCar = d.name; //not work
String nameOfTheCar = ((Car)d.name); //not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two way to do it.

Make the interface aware of the property (implementing it in the class), eg.:

```
public interface Drive {
     String getName();
}
```

Otherwise you have to cast the interface object to the type which contains the property you, you already did it, but with a wrong syntax:

```
 String nameOfTheCar = ((Car)d.name); //not work
```

Instead of:

```
String nameOfTheCar = ((Car) d).name; //not work
```